# Select rows at random in R under certain conditions

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

From the **original** sample dataset:

```
id <- c('1','1','2', '2', '3', '3', '3')
month <- c('6', '6', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4')
iso <- c('MEX', 'USA', 'CRI', 'SPA', 'CHN', 'MEX', 'SPA')
value <- c('1550', '1550', '384', '115', '1100', '1100', '1100')
original <- data.frame(id, month, iso, value)
```

I want to end up with only **1 observation** for each id-month pair.
The rule to follow is:

1. Choose the **maximum** value for each id-month pair.
2. In case there is the **same** maximum value for the different observations of the same id-month pair, I want to choose one of the rows at random.

Therefore, the **new** sample dataset will look like this:

```
id <- c('1', '2', '3')
month <- c('6', '3', '4')
iso <- c('USA', 'CRI','MEX')
value <- c('1550', '384', '1100')
selection_criteria <- c('random','max_value','random')
new <- data.frame(id, month, iso, value, selection_criteria)
```

I have tried to run the following code:

```
new <- original %>% group_by(id, month) %>%
  filter(value == max(value))
```

However, it does not make the trick of selecting one variable at random when I have more than one observation (for the same id-month pair) with a maximum value.

My intention is to automatise the process given the large dimension of my dataset.

Any clue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Old Answer**

```
set.seed(2021)

new <- original %>% group_by(id, month) %>%
  slice_max(as.numeric(value)) %>% sample_n(1)

> new
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   id, month [3]
  id    month iso   value
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1     6     MEX   1550 
2 2     3     CRI   384  
3 3     4     MEX   1100
```

slice_max will cause filtering all max of values rows in each group.  Further sample_n(size =1) will again restrict one row in each group

---

However, the approach suggested by other user is better as it reduces the number of steps-

```
set.seed(2021)

original %>% 
  group_by(id, month) %>% 
  slice_max(order_by = as.numeric(value), n = 1, with_ties = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. `which.max` is the more canonical way of matching the max value, instead of `val == max(val)`; while unlikely with this data, if your data has differences in the small-decimal range, then floating-point equality can be a problem (c.f., [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518), [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004), and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754); I'm going to recommend a different approach entirely ...
2. `rank` will tell you which values are the highest/lowest, and it's pretty straight forward to look for a rank of 1. In the presence of ties, it has several options, one of which is `"random"`.

   ```r
   rank(c(1,1), ties = "first")
   # [1] 1 2
   rank(c(1,1), ties = "last")
   # [1] 2 1
   rank(c(1,1), ties = "average")
   # [1] 1.5 1.5
   rank(c(1,1), ties = "random")
   # [1] 1 2
   rank(c(1,1), ties = "random")
   # [1] 2 1
   ```
3. You're looking for `max` of a string, which will not always return the maximum numeric value from among the strings. For example, `max(c("9", "11"))` returns `"9"`, since it uses lexicographic sorting. If you want the maximum *numeric* value, then we need to convert (at least temporarily) to numbers. If your intent truly is to sort alphabetically, and you want 9 to be greater than 11, then remove the `as.numeric`.

```r
set.seed(2020)
original %>%
  group_by(id, month) %>%
  filter(rank(as.numeric(value), ties = "random") == 1L)
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
# # Groups:   id, month [3]
#   id    month iso   value
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 1     6     USA   1550 
# 2 2     3     SPA   115  
# 3 3     4     MEX   1100 

set.seed(2021)
original %>%
  group_by(id, month) %>%
  filter(rank(as.numeric(value), ties = "random") == 1L)
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
# # Groups:   id, month [3]
#   id    month iso   value
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 1     6     MEX   1550 
# 2 2     3     SPA   115  
# 3 3     4     CHN   1100
```

---

### Side Note

@AnilGoyal's answer suggests a more dplyr-idiomatic solution, using `slice_max` and `sample_n`. If you prefer to stay within the tidyverse with verbs that are more declarative, then perhaps that's a good way to go (since readability and maintainability are important).

Your data does not suggest that you're doing this in a large dataset, in which case benchmarking is not important. If I'm incorrect, and you do need to be concerned about performance, then the `dplyr`-only solution is a little slower.

```r
# pre-group the data so that that isn't in the benchmark comparison;
# also, `as.numeric` is used in both, do that ahead of time
original_grouped <- mutate(original, value_num = as.numeric(value)) %>%
  group_by(id, month)

bench::mark(
  base = filter(original_grouped, rank(value_num, ties = "random") == 1L),
  dplyr = sample_n(slice_max(original_grouped, value_num), 1),
  check = FALSE)
# # A tibble: 2 x 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory                  time           gc                
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>                  <list>         <list>            
# 1 base         1.07ms   1.16ms      815.    9.34KB     4.18   390     2      478ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [8 x 3]>  <bch:tm [392]> <tibble [392 x 3]>
# 2 dplyr        2.25ms   2.45ms      378.   10.66KB     6.44   176     3      466ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [11 x 3]> <bch:tm [179]> <tibble [179 x 3]>
```

Though that advantage is decreased with larger data:

```r
original_big <- bind_rows(replicate(10000, original, simplify = FALSE))
original_big_grouped <- mutate(original_big, value_num = as.numeric(value)) %>%
  group_by(id, month)
bench::mark(base = filter(original_big_grouped, rank(value_num, ties = "random") == 1L), dplyr = sample_n(slice_max(original_big_grouped, value_num), 1), check = FALSE)
# # A tibble: 2 x 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory                   time          gc               
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>                   <list>        <list>           
# 1 base          6.9ms   7.47ms      128.    4.82MB     16.0    48     6      375ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [50 x 3]>  <bch:tm [54]> <tibble [54 x 3]>
# 2 dplyr        7.61ms   8.23ms      119.   11.65MB     71.1    25    15      211ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [106 x 3]> <bch:tm [40]> <tibble [40 x 3]>
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of `ties = "random"` argument.  Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(original)[, .SD[which.max(value)], .(id, month)]
```